# rxjs how to access previous param using withLatestFrom

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Using RxJs 6

Here's an excerpt from an RxJs pipe:

```
.pipe(
  tap((action) => console.log(action)),
  // error is on following line
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectBim(action.payload)))),
  ...
)
```

The error in my IDE is `Cannot find name 'action'` and runtime error is `action is not defined`.

But in withLatestFrom I need to access `action`. How can I do this? Thx

Comment: Why not use a `flatMap` instead of `withLatestFrom`?

Comment: could you provide an example how plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could just use a [`flatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) (alias for `mergeMap`) operator instead:

```
.pipe(
  flatMap((action) => this.store.pipe(select(selectSim(action.payload)))),
  tap((action) => console.log(action)),
  ...
)
```

This should print the value of the second observable (from your `store`). If you need both, you could use [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) or [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) probably, or just save the `action` value to some outer-scoped variable.

Comment: switchMap with a forkJoin inside did it - many thanks - also the outer-scoped variable approach works too

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, here is what worked:

```
mergeMap((action) => forkJoin(
  of(action),
  this.store.pipe(select(selectBim(action.payload))).take(1),
  this.store.pipe(select(selectCurrentBim)).take(1)
)),
map(([action, requestedBim, currentBim]) => ({requestedBimId: action.payload, requestedBim, currentBim})),
```

Now I have access to all the data in the map statement following the mergeMap

`withLatestFrom` is much more concise if you do not need to access `action` in the parameters given to `withLatestFrom`

Comment: this will work but is generally an anti pattern in ngrx.  The action payload should contain all information needed to modify the state.  Having to acess the state itself in order to further modify the state is almost always a bad / difficult to maintain approach.

Comment: I was taught to use withLatestFrom and to use ngrx selectors in the withLatestFrom params - this is taught on the NgRx 6 Udemy course - however, in using what I had been taught I came across the need to access action in the withLatestFrom params - and that's why I was driven down this route - could you point to an article to confirm what you are saying - many thanks - love constructive feedback